# How to shuffle the results of two MySQL SELECT statements

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query which will `SELECT` from a table where `status = 1` and `SELECT` from the same table where `status = 6`. I want the final result to be limited to just six, and for the final result to be randomly selected(shuffled). I tried using `ORDER BY rand()`, but it is returning the same result, without any shuffling (random selection). 
Here's my query:

```
(SELECT * FROM fpf_adverts WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY rand())
UNION ALL
(SELECT e.*FROM fpf_adverts e JOIN fpf_adverts ee ON e.status + 6 > ee.status WHERE e.status = 6) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that ?

```
        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM fpf_adverts
        WHERE status IN (1,6)
        ORDER BY status
        LIMIT 6) t
        ORDER BY RAND()
```

---

Previous answer

Try that ?

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM fpf_adverts WHERE status = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.*
    FROM fpf_adverts e
    INNER JOIN fpf_adverts ee ON e.status + 6 > ee.status
    WHERE e.status = 6) t
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 6
```

But if you just want to filter by status 1 or 6, better

```
    SELECT *
    FROM fpf_adverts
    WHERE status IN (1,6)
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Thanks @MateoBarahona. The main idea is to **first** get all the results of where `status = 1` and then complete the count to 6 with the results of where `status = 6`. For example, let's say `status = 1` returns 4 rows, I want the remaining two rows to be completed with `status = 6`, and then the final result be shuffled (randomized).

Comment: Amended to reflect your precision

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Mateo, I have only one row were `status = 6` and I'm using this query `(SELECT e.*FROM fpf_adverts e JOIN fpf_adverts ee ON e.status + 6 > ee.status WHERE e.status = 6)` to duplicate it up to six times. So, omitting it, did not complete the rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93952/discussion-between-samuel-asor-and-mateo-barahona).